# CheckBox doesn't display selector on black background?

Tags: android

I'm trying add a CheckBox, the problem is the background of LinearLayout is black and the selector of CheckBox doesn't display to check. Checkboxes are `Brinde and Entrega Futura` in picture.

How could I solve it ?

[image]

```
<CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/cbEntregaFutura"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:text="Entrega Futura"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
```

Comment: Provide the button drawable which can be visible on black background like android:button="@drawable/check_box_white"

Comment: very nice, could you create an answer to check ?